# Replacing duplicate list elements with NaN

Tags: python, list, duplicates

I would like to replace all duplicates of elements in arrays with `NaN`.
For example:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5]
```

Goal:

```
a = [NaN, NaN, 2, 3, NaN, 8, NaN, 6, 7, NaN, NaN]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count all instances of each element in `a`,
and then create a new `a` based on the count:

```py
from collections import Counter

a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5]
histogram = Counter(a)

a = [n if histogram[n]<=1 else None for n in a]
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

> **Python List count() Method**
>
> The count() method returns the number of elements with the specified
>   value.
>
> *Syntax*
>
> ```
> list.count(value)
> ```

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5]

result = ([x if a.count(x) == 1 else None for x in a ]) 

print (result)
```

output:

```
[None, None, 2, 3, None, 8, None, 6, 7, None, None]
```

what is equivalent to:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5]

result = []
for x in a:
    # For each item, check how many times it will appear in the list
    if a.count(x) == 1:  # if item only appears once, append it to the list
        result.append(x)
    else: # if item appears more than once, append None to the list
        result.append(None)

print (result)
```

output:

```
[None, None, 2, 3, None, 8, None, 6, 7, None, None]
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not pretty but i think it keeps the cost low.

```
import math

seen = []
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 8, 5, 6, 7, 5, 5]

for e in a:
    if e not in seen and not math.isnan(e):
        seen.append(e)
    else:
        indexes = ([i for i, x in enumerate(a) if x == e])
        for val in indexes:
            a[val] = float('NaN')

print(a)
```